# Import error: Cannot import name ExchangeNTLMAuthConnection

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyexchange

This is my python error stack trace. I'm using pyexchange, a package used to interact with Microsoft Exchange servers.

I'd like to know which part fails exactly. It had a lot of dependencies and I had trouble installing a few of them - lxml, libxml2, urllib3 etc.

I'm running this on Windows 7. On MacOS X, this runs smoothly. Only on windows, I have these issues. I'm suspecting something didn't get properly installed, but not sure what. When I try to reinstall a package, it says requirements met. Tried upgrading too.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "calendar.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyexchange import Exchange2010Service, ExchangeNTLMAuthConnection
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexchange\__init__.py", line 9, in <modul
e>
    from .connection import ExchangeNTLMAuthConnection  # noqa
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexchange\connection.py", line 7, in <mod
ule>
    import requests
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 60, in <module
>
    from .packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 29, i
n <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 35, in <m
odule>
    from .request import RequestMethods
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .filepost import encode_multipart_formdata
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\filepost.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .fields import RequestField
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\fields.py", line 2, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\utils.py", line 32, in <module>
    from email._parseaddr import quote
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\_parseaddr.py", line 16, in <module>
    import time, calendar
  File "c:\alexa-calendar\calendar.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyexchange import Exchange2010Service, ExchangeNTLMAuthConnection
ImportError: cannot import name ExchangeNTLMAuthConnection
```

Comment: No, they don't seem to talk about the package I'm seeing issues with, at all. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the current log shared, The package `ExchangeNTLMAuthConnection` doesn't seems to be available on your Python Distribution installed on your Windows Operating System.

Install the same using the following command

```
pip install ExchangeNTLMAuthConnection
```